# Continuous flow of content of multi line div's without line-breaks

Tags: html, css

There are three divs having width 100%, each div contains 3 inner div's having width 50%, such that

```
<style type="text/css">
     .inner{
        width: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
     }
     .outer{
        width: 100%;
     }
</style>
<div class="outer">
     <div class="inner"> content </div><div class="inner"> content </div><div class="inner"> content </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
     <div class="inner"> content </div><div class="inner"> content </div><div class="inner"> content </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
     <div class="inner"> content </div><div class="inner"> content </div><div class="inner"> content </div>
</div>
```

Now my question is how can I have two inner elements on each row ie, no line break, right now there is a line break after each 3'rd inner element, such that the effect will become same as this,

```
   <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"> content </div><div class="inner"> content </div><div class="inner"> content </div><div class="inner"> content </div><div class="inner"> content </div><div class="inner"> content </div><div class="inner"> content </div><div class="inner"> content </div><div class="inner"> content </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using float and now I am out of ideas,
-Regards

Comment: This is because every `inner`div takes up 50% of the `outer` div. So there is only room for two. If you change the `inner` width to 33%, it will display perfectly. However I don't think this is what you mean. Can you me more specific? :)

Comment: For this class .inner used width:33% instead of the 50%.Because outer div class width is 100%.So for that you need to divide all 3 div's in same width like. 33% if you are using 5 div's then 20% and so on.

Comment: I must have only two divs each row, that's why the width on inner div's must be 50%,

Answer (score 1):

May be you want this please check.

```css
  .inner{
        width: 50%; float:left;
        display: inline-block;
     }
     .outer{
        width: 100%;
     }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
     <div class="inner"> content </div><div class="inner"> content </div><div class="inner"> content </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
     <div class="inner"> content </div><div class="inner"> content </div><div class="inner"> content </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
     <div class="inner"> content </div><div class="inner"> content </div><div class="inner"> content </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 .inner{
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
 }
 .outer{
    width: 100%;
 }
```

Add this in css to fix the issue.Sometimes few browser have some issue.The exat soln will be 33.33 but do it less like 30% or 32% so. Hope you got your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here you need divide 100 / Number of div.

**If you wanted to display 2 div's then 100/2 = 50%**. So you need to set class `width 50%`.

```
like (100/3)  = 33.33
```

So you need to set

```
.inner{
        width: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
     }
```

Comment: He want to have `two` inner elements on one row, not three.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening due to the inner width that is 50%
since two divs already occupy the 100% so there is a line break. so if the inner width is :33% then it will accommodate the three inner divs. if you want more inner divs just divide 100/n, where n is the no of divs and you will get the right width.

```css
.inner {
  width: 32%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.outer {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"> content </div>
  <div class="inner"> content </div>
  <div class="inner"> content </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"> content </div>
  <div class="inner"> content </div>
  <div class="inner"> content </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"> content </div>
  <div class="inner"> content </div>
  <div class="inner"> content </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we need to accommodate 3 div inline ,so width of one div = 100/3 = 33.But we take width of inner div = 32% , as there is 2px gap between inline-blocks. 
Change width of inner div to 32% ,as you have to accommodate 3 inline-block in given width of parent div.Below is demonstration:

```css
.bigBox
{
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
    background: grey;
}

.box{
    width: 32%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="bigBox">
    <div class="box">
     content1
    </div>
    <div class="box">
     content2
    </div>
    <div class="box">
     content3
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
```

And this mentioned by @Rubenxfd in above comment.Hope this helps :)